# Changing the appearance of my @IBAction button in Swift out of its func

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton, ibaction

I'm writing an app in which there's a scrollview and what I want is to set the button's alpha to 0 at first and change it into 1 when the user scrolls to the last page. I'm writing code like this:

```
@IBAction func startButton(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
        sender.alpha = 0.0
 }

extension UserGuideViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let offset = scrollView.contentOffset
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(offset.x / view.bounds.width)
        if pageControl.currentPage == numberOfPages - 1 {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
                self.startButton.alpha = 1.0
            }
        } else {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2) {
                self.startButton.alpha = 0.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and it says the `Value of type (UIButton)->() has no member alpha`. I don't know how to do this. 
I know it would be easy if this button is an @IBOutlet but I need to set it as an @IBAction so that when it gets touched I can show another view controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create *both* an `@IBOutlet` and an `@IBAction` for the button. Drag twice from Interface Builder to your view controller and select the appropriate values (outlet or action) from the popup menu and give them different names. Then access the outlet in your `scrollViewDidScroll` method.

Comment: @Allen, You should accept the answer if it solves your problem. (Click the check-mark.) This is an important thing to do on SO. It lets others reading the thread know that this is the correct answer.

Comment: Yes I was about to do this.